# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rolling' ,after making array to dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, time-series, numpy-ndarray

I converted my numpy array to dataframe, however the error still remains

```
deseanolized_df = pd.DataFrame(deseanolized)
df_ma = deseanolized_df.values.rolling(3,center=True,closed='both').mean()
df_ma.plot()
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_40/956302484.py in <module>
      1 deseanolized_df = pd.DataFrame(deseanolized)
----> 2 df_ma = deseanolized_df.values.rolling(3,center=True,closed='both').mean()
      3 df_ma.plot()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rolling'
```

Comment: Use `deseanolized_df.rolling(...)`, not `deseanolized_df.values.rolling(...)`.

Comment: `deseanolized_df.values` returns a numpy array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`deseanolized_df.values` is the underlying numpy array. Basically, you converted to dataframe to convert back to numpy.

Use:

```
deseanolized_df.rolling(3, center=True, closed='both').mean()
```